# A modular identity

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

Is it true that

$p \equiv 1 (\mod{6}) \iff p \equiv 1 (\mod{12}) \vee p \equiv -5 (\mod{12})$.

It's obvious that $p \equiv 1 (\mod{12}) \vee p \equiv -5 (\mod{12}) \implies p \equiv 1 (\mod{6})$. But, what about the converse?

Comment: $p\equiv 1\pmod{12}\iff p=6(2k)+1$ and $p\equiv 7\pmod{12}\iff p=6(2k+1)+1$ for some $k\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Both directions are easy. For the direction I think you are concerned about, note that for example if $p=12k-5$ then $p=6(2k-1)+1$.

Comment: Obvious... if $p=6h+1$, then $h$ can be odd (for example $h=2k-1$) or even (for example $h=2k$). In this way I can conclude.

Comment: Is $p$ a prime?

Comment: You can use \pmod command. For example `p\equiv1\pmod6` produces $p\equiv1\pmod6$. (Notice the different spacing.) TeX.SE: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137073/writing-mod-in-congruence-problems-without-leading-space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$p\equiv 1\pmod{6}$ means $p=6k+1$ for some $k$. Now there are two cases: if $k$ is even, $k=2n$, then $p=12n+1$ implies $p\equiv 1\pmod{12}$. If $k$ is odd, $k=2n+1$, then $p=12n+7$ implies $p\equiv 7\pmod{12}$. Nothing else may happen.